# Tengo un "403 forbidden" en mi sitio web desplegado en pythonanyhwere

Tags: python, django, web, vscode, app

mundo, estoy experimentando un error de 403 forbidden cuando despliego mi app web en pythonanyhwere, puntualmente esta url no me deja ingresar: https://francisxocab.pythonanywhere.com/cargar_artista/

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

tengo un problema parecido pero con un 404.
[ésta es mi pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/610451/problema-con-rutas-en-pythonanywhere-carga-home-pero-no-el-resto-de-las-p%C3%A1ginas)

no muestras nada de código como para poder ayudarte

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).