# problema con rutas en pythonanywhere, carga home pero no el resto de las páginas

Tags: django, rutas, despliegue

Hice el despliegue y fue bastante complejo por mi inexperiencia, pero he podigo solucionar casi todo hasta ahora que quedé atascado.
Los videotutoriales ayudaron, pero las rutas que ponía en las variables no me coincidían hasta que probé pequeñas variaciones y dí en el clavo.
El sitio ahora carga, reconoce los archivos estáticos, pero no puedo ingresar a ninguna subpágina, todas dan error 404, incluso el admin de django.
La aplicación funciona perfecto en local, pero no puedo hacerle cargar subpáginas en pythonanywhere.
A continuación detallo lo necesario para que quien tenga experiencia por favor me ayude. Desde ya muchas gracias.

La pestaña web tiene los siguientes valores:

```
Source code: /home/tomylocproject/tomyloc/tomyloc
Working directory: /home/tomylocproject
WSGI configuration file: /var/www/tomylocproject_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py
```

lo cual luce así:

```
import os
import sys

path = os.path.expanduser('~/tomyloc')
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, path)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'tomyloc.settings'
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import StaticFilesHandler
application = StaticFilesHandler(get_wsgi_application())
```

```
Python version: 3.10
Virtualenv: /home/tomylocproject/.virtualenvs/tomyloc
Access log: tomylocproject.pythonanywhere.com.access.log
Error log: tomylocproject.pythonanywhere.com.error.log
Server log: tomylocproject.pythonanywhere.com.server.log

Static files:
/static/ /home/tomylocproject/tomyloc/static     
/media/ /home/tomylocproject/tomyloc/media
```

Estructura:

```
tomylocproject
--------.virtualenvs/
--------tomyloc
----------------accounts/
------------------------__init__py
------------------------admin.py
------------------------apps.py
------------------------forms.py
------------------------models.py
------------------------tests.py
------------------------urls.py
------------------------views.py
----------------map/
------------------------__init__py
------------------------admin.py
------------------------apps.py
------------------------forms.py
------------------------models.py
------------------------tests.py
------------------------urls.py
------------------------views.py            
----------------media/
----------------static/
----------------templates/
------------------------accounts/
--------------------------------404.html
--------------------------------500.html
--------------------------------home.html
--------------------------------loginpage.html
--------------------------------message.html
--------------------------------registerpage.html
------------------------map/
--------------------------------map.html
----------------tomyloc/
------------------------__init__py
------------------------asgi.py 
------------------------setting.py
------------------------urls.py     
------------------------wsgi.py
----------------manage.py
----------------tomyloc.sqlite3
```

Lo principal del settings.py:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

DEBUG = False

if DEBUG:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['tomylocproject', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']
else:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] #así carga, sino no lo hace


# Application definition

BASE_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

THIRD_APPS = [
]

OWN_APPS = [
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'map.apps.MapConfig'
]


INSTALLED_APPS = BASE_APPS + THIRD_APPS + OWN_APPS


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'tomyloc.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'tomyloc.wsgi.application'



STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

LOCALE_PATHS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale')]
```

urls.py de tomyloc (/home/tomylocproject/tomyloc/tomyloc/urls.py):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls import handler404, handler500
from accounts.views import error_404_view, error_500_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('', include('map.urls')),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

handler404 = 'accounts.views.error_404_view'
handler500 = 'accounts.views.error_500_view'
```

urls.py de accounts (/home/tomylocproject/tomyloc/accounts/urls.py):

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('loginPage/', views.loginPage, name="loginPage"),
    path('registerPage/', views.registerPage, name="registerPage"),
    path('logout/', views.logoutUser, name="logout"),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

urls.py de map (/home/tomylocproject/tomyloc/map/urls.py):

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import map
from .views import addEnterpriseToMap
from .views import listUserEnterprises
from .views import addLocation
from .views import updateLocation
from .views import deleteLocation
from . import views

app_name = 'map'

urlpatterns = [
    path('map/', map, name='map'),
    path('addEnterpriseToMap/', addEnterpriseToMap, name='addEnterpriseToMap'),
    path('listUserEnterprises/', listUserEnterprises, name='listUserEnterprises'),
    path('addEnterpriseAdvertising/<int:location_id>/',
         views.addEnterpriseAdvertising, name='addEnterpriseAdvertising'),
    path('reactiveAdvertising/<int:advertisement_id>/',
         views.reactiveAdvertising, name='reactiveAdvertising'),
    path('deactiveAdvertising/<int:advertisement_id>/',
         views.deactiveAdvertising, name='deactiveAdvertising'),
    path('addLocation/', addLocation, name='addLocation'),
    path('updateLocation/<int:location_id>/',
         updateLocation, name='updateLocation'),
    path('deleteLocation/<int:location_id>/',
         deleteLocation, name='deleteLocation'),
    path('locationInfo/<int:location_id>/',
         views.locationInfo, name='locationInfo'),
]
```